# Are military units marching in military parades considered military or civilian targets?

Tags: military, rules-of-war, war-crime

Russian Federation is widely expected to conduct its annual military parade on May 9th.  The parade traditionally takes places on the Red Square with many "military units" marching over a prolonged period of time.  There is little, if any, room around the parading military that is taken up by civilians.

While it would be an act of war for another country to bomb those military units, would it be a war "crime?"  Are marching military units, most of which look like showmen rather than actual soldiers, considered military?  Or are they civilians despite the uniforms?

Edit (May 11th, 2023):

It's almost funny how well this question has aged.

It's a year later, and there are now [media reports](https://www.cnbc.com/2023/05/10/putins-one-tank-military-parade-was-an-embarrassment-for-russia.html) that Russia's 2023 "Victory Day" **parade has been significantly scaled down precisely because of the security concerns** about possible drone attacks by Ukraine.

The question is as relevant now as it was back when I first asked it.

This question is **particularly relevant to this war** because so much of it revolves around cat-n-mouse hunting of opposing military's units by both sides.  And, of course, thousands of troops on display, concentrated in one place, would make for an easy target.

So the question of whether such an attack would violate the laws of war is more relevant than ever.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a good fit for here as I think this would be a legal or military matter and not politics.

Comment: @JoeW military questions are probably within scope of the site.  "politics".SE is a site to ask questions about governments and how they function rather than just political processes.  In fact you can see from the tags "military" and "war-crime," applied to this question, that there is any number of questions about military that maybe on topic.  Any question which asks about procedures involved in making of government decisions is on topic.

Comment: A march in a War is kind of not very smart. Similar to a rally in a pandemics.

Comment: *would it be a war "crime?"* translates to "Given the preceding circumstances, [what is the law?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2704/26455). The two following questions may also be answered by "what is the law?"

Comment: @RickSmith only if there is a law.  If, for example, it's a political decision, or even a mix of a political and legal decision, then the is only a limited component of it.

Comment: @wrod - [Are 'war crimes' written down in laws?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79066/are-war-crimes-written-down-in-laws) on [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @RickSmith from the accepted answer: "The analysis in the case of war crimes is **not as contractarian as in other areas** of international treaty enforcement and international law."  That's another way of saying that it's political.

Comment: This belongs on worldbuilding, not politics.

Comment: Seems like a pretty good idea for a movie...

Comment: These are technically members of military, but not presenting any direct threat. Attacking them is more a matter of symbolism/propaganda than of actual military value. I'd say it is like shooting paratroopers before they land, which is off limits.

Comment: @RogerVadim as I pointed out in the other comment, the reference (which actually sources the Geneva Conventions directly) states that descending paratroopers are **not off limits.**  The people using parachutes are off limits when its clear that they are evacuating (e.g. pilots from a disabled aircraft).  Furthermore, they don't need to be presenting a direct threat.  Bombing military sleeping quarters is fair game.

Comment: @RogerVadim: "shooting paratroopers before they land, which is off limits".  Actually, it isn't. Germany did this during Market Garden, but nobody was [then] prosecuted for it, despite ample opportunities.

Comment: @Fizz it has been already cleared in the comments to the answer by o.m. Also, I wouldn't hold Germany in WW2 as a standard for respecting Geneva conventions - even on western front they violated them towards the end.

Comment: @RogerVadim: In case you misunderstood: I was referring to the Allies not having prosecuted any Germans for that ( "shooting paratroopers before they land") despite ample opportunities for "victor's justice" in the aftermath.

Comment: @Fizz As I said, it is cleared in other comments - with a reference to Wikipedia, which has a rather clear article on the matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems everybody is reading up on the law of war these days, just like everybody became a virologist last year ... well, here are my two cents.

- Members of the armed forces of a conflict party, except for medics and chaplains, will be combatants even if they are not actively fighting at the moment.
- Participation in a parade is not a sign of surrender, or a sign of unconsciousness or injury that prevents showing surrender.
- It is illegal to (knowingly) shell a field hospital. It is legal to shell a barracks with sleeping troops. I'd say the parade is much like the latter -- just because they don't have air raid protections doesn't make them immune.

So if the Ukraine were to send a bunch of *uniformed* troops overland to Moscow, to shell the parade, that would have to be tested for the usual *distinction,* *proportionality*, and *necessity* requirements when it comes to probable civilian casualties. They don't have to avoid all civilian casualties, as long as enough combatants are targeted.

That being said, it would certainly be **viewed as escalatory** by Russia. That's not a legal term, it is a strategic/geopolitical one. Just as the US public finds it *normal* to have their aircraft carriers bomb foreign countries, and *not normal* to have foreign navies shoot at the carriers, Russia seems to find it *normal* to have their troops fight in Ukraine, and *not normal* if Ukraine would fight in Russia -- see the diplomatic tightrope about the [Belgorod](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-60952125) explosions.

Ukraine would have to ask if the military effort and political risk are worth it. I guess not.

Comment: Russian media: "Ukrainian Nazi turn to terrorism to avenge the defeat of their German brothers in WWII. More on Ukraine's role in Hitler's forces in the following special..."

Comment: @wrod, escalation comes in steps. Back in there Cold War days, there were doctrines which viewed evacuating the *own* urban centers as more escalatory than isolated nuclear attacks on the enemy [Rand report](https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/reports/2007/R3235.pdf). Russia is clearly signalling that some possible steps are more escalatory than others.

Comment: @o.m.  my point was that Russia has blown through all the escalation steps at this point.  Short of using nuclear weapons, it's done the worst things it could possibly do.  It literally leveled a whole city with convention arms (for example).  It's also sent numerous assassination squads against Zelensky.  Russia has no room escalate.

Comment: @wrod, there is *a lot* Russia could do to escalate further. They're not shelling NATO members, they haven't cut all trade, ...

Comment: @o.m. NATO is neutral in this conflict (as in it's not a warring party).  Which is not to say that it doesn't have its favorite, but even Lavrov [has admitted that Russia does not consider NATO to be one of the belligerents](https://www.reuters.com/world/russia-does-not-consider-itself-war-with-nato-blames-kyiv-talks-deadlock-2022-04-29/).  "Escalation" usually does not mean attacking a 3rd party.  It means increasing the level of hostilities towards those already on the opposite side in a war.

Comment: @wrod, both NATO and Russia believe that they are in a geopolitical struggle against each other, even if it benefits both sides not to be at war.

Comment: @o.m. Russia is also in a geo-political struggle with China.  Would you suggest that Russia might bomb China in response Ukraine making incursions into the Russian territory?  I wouldn't think so.  A neutral party is neutral.  It doesn't matter what causes it to be neutral.  Engaging a neutral party militarily is tantamount to starting a new aggression (the way that Russia started a new and unprovoked aggression against Ukraine).

Comment: "Ukraine would be foolish NOT to bomb the parade" -- if they haven't made any retaliatory strikes on Russia yet, I don't see why they would do so then. They may be trying to maintain the moral high ground by acting purely defensively.

Comment: @Barmar, as to morals, the means and accuracy would matter. Special forces delivering explosives would *look* much like a terrorist attack, even if they wore uniform and it was all appropriate under the laws of war. A missile could be off just a little bit, and hit the wrong street. Getting a manned helicopter in would be close to impossible.

Comment: Even combattants cannot be attacked, if they do jot represent any danger - like paratroopers in air or prisoners of war.

Comment: @RogerVadim paratroopers landing for the assault can be attacked. Only pilots and crew from the downed aircraft not.

Comment: @Stančikas they can be attacked once on the ground.

Comment: @RogerVadim https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/fr/customary-ihl/v2/rule48

Comment: @Stančikas your link does not concern the situation we discussing, but rather an aircraft in distress. However, you do have a valid point, judging by what is written here: [30. Persons Descending by Parachute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attacks_on_parachutists). But it says specifically *persons who are or appear to be bound upon hostile missions* - not sure how this applies to parades or musicians in a military band.

Comment: "just as the US public finds...": Citation needed. I'm a member of the US public, and I find that both actions would be normal under some circumstances and abnormal under others, mostly related to provocation, retaliation, and proportionality (or the lack of these factors).  Beyond the usual hyperbolic political posturing and spin, do you have evidence supporting your assertion about US public opinion?

Comment: @wrod doesn't escalation also include widening the geographical scope?  Russia could escalate the war by opening a front in western Ukraine.

Comment: @phoog if they could attack the West, they probably would have done it already.  They certainly have less of an opportunity to do it now than when they were close to Kyiv, which has roads leading West. It's a mountainous forest area -- partisan's playground.  It's essentially only assailable with infantry.  This is entirely different from the steppe terrain, where the fighting is now.

Comment: @RogerVadim the ["attack on parachutests"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attacks_on_parachutists), which you cited, clearly refers to those evacuating, by parachute, from "a disabled aircraft" ("disable aircraft" is a direct quote).  Paratroopers are not it. To quote, "firing on airborne forces who are descending by parachute (i.e. paratroopers) is **not** prohibited."

Comment: @wrod there's my later comments, where I correct myself and cite specific conditions, where such firing is allowed.

Comment: @wrod I'm not asking about what's practical or possible; I'm clarifying the definition of "escalation" to establish that Russia could escalate the conflict otherwise than by using nuclear weapons. Russia surely could escalate the ground war by mobilizing its entire military-age population, but political considerations make that difficult, just as it is difficult to use nuclear weapons for political reasons.  Compare Russia's current mobilization to that of WW2.  There is plenty of room to escalate without resorting to nukes. Whether Russia would choose to use that room is another matter.

Comment: @phoog and my point was that short was using nuclear weapons Russia hasn't been holding back anything it can do.  So there is no room left for escalation.

Comment: @RogerVadim alright.  so I guess we settled that paratroopers are fair game.  Assuming the qualification "persons who are or appear to be bound upon hostile missions" is what you mean by "specific conditions, where such firing is allowed," I guess that's probably what the question itself is about -- whether they can be treated as bound for combat.

Comment: @wrod likely not: these are "elite units" - "elite" in the sense that they serve in prestigious places, like Kremlin or Moscow region, not because of their training. Most weapons on display are likely not real ones (apart from tanks and anything that moves itself.) Interesting case is the parade of 1941, when the units went from the parade directly into combat (at least, this is what the legend says.) But Germans on eastern front didn't worry about committing war crimes.

Answer (score 3):

I have used a [2003 year article](https://hhi.harvard.edu/sites/hwpi.harvard.edu/files/humanitarianinitiative/files/session1_legitimate_targets_ihl.pdf?m=1615827575) "Legitimate targets of attacks under international humanitarian law" by Marco Sassòli, professor of international law at the University of Quebec at Montreal, Canada. Following this article, a valid military target:

- has to contribute effectively to the military action of the enemy
- its destruction, capture, or neutralization has to offer a definite military advantage for the other side
- only material, tangible thing can be a target.

The article further warns that these rules should not be interpreted excessively widely because otherwise about anything can become a military target.

From this looks like that a military parade where lots of modern weapons and thousands of combat-ready troops are marching should be a valid military target, as destroying all this army would bring a military advantage. Further, following the article, it can be no "half combatant" status, and these soldiers are still likely more combatants than civilians.

From the other side, the attack must still be done honestly and collateral damage to civilians must be proportional. For instance, during the [2018 year attack on Ahvaz military parade](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/09/24/world/middleeast/iran-attack-military-parade.html?unlocked_article_code=h62hS4fdlquT3JcHGCEcEZcC4PJdPPuSTlmzRGxwV3g1AMzp98P2L-a-Nvzpk9jm6m0trb-3SMwC7JXT3eKPCefvjfCKqob4w8E6raaIaYujzKeqB98tSOKAWKcskdcOKDwheYwWZRuj3PzaXf3ujyfrFnpFrw3LRs4pZHpYvGAYSxoTBQCKHWkLKgDPv4kWeZQN2iF08i4HS-YrkyP4eeJ90dms4uC7uXXko3xERnvea9Zn5xGWAHRVT7lfQ_Z2jk87qSsULN7J_GEOA5Xp6Ktv7-gRSA_ToctPx2fI3lYF0qy6K4HwjYppB7fH3SGQpWyH1x-5k6WpAMfHOmxikHS97k1vuj1q3LO1isgyoA&smid=url-share) in Iran, the attackers killed 25 people, including 12 soldiers. While a prominent academic in the emirate of Abu Dhabi, who has frequently been described as an adviser to the Emirati government, have said that “A military attack against a military target is not a terrorist act”, the Ahvaz attack later [has been condemned](https://press.un.org/en/2018/sc13523.doc.htm) by UN. However the UN document does not state specifically if any attack on a parade is illegitimate by itself or something else has contributed to this, like fake military uniforms used by attackers or too large proportion of civilians killed. 1:1 is quite a [common proportion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilian_casualty_ratio) for a war overall but specific strikes are expected to be more specific. NATO claims they have been as good as 1:10 in Yugoslavia bombings, 1:5 in Pakistan and Israeli 1:3 in 2008–09 Gaza War (opponents tend to question these numbers).

Comment: "NATO claims they have been as good as 1:10 in Yugoslavia bombings, 1:5 in Pakistan and Israeli 1:3 in 2008–09 Gaza War." Here 1 is the number of cilivians or soldiers? I always thought that Israel killed many more Civilians than combatants in the Gaza Wars.

Comment: 1 is the number of civilians. Less civilians should be killed than soldiers. These numbers are usually a topic of hot debates, with opponents claiming that more civilians have been killed. In recent war overall, with starving and the like included, this is most often close to 1:1.

Comment: Since the goal set for the bounty was to get more details, this answer should get it because it gives a specific example of the principle that the question is asking about.

Answer (score 2):

As we saw after a couple of drones exploded over the Kremlin (somewhat [close](https://www.theguardian.com/world/video/2023/may/03/drone-seen-exploding-over-the-kremlin-video) to the empty stands from where the parade was going to be watched), Russia [called it](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/05/03/europe/ukraine-drone-attack-putin-kremlin-intl/index.html) a terrorist attack.

> Ukraine denied involvement in the alleged strike. [...]
>
> The Kremlin Press Service has called the purported drone attack an “attempt on the President’s life,” said it was an “act of terrorism” and blamed Ukraine. [...]
>
> In his response to the attack, Russian State Duma Speaker Vyacheslav Volodin called for the use of weapons capable of “stopping and destroying the Kyiv terrorist regime.”

So it doesn't matter too much what international law says about any of this, as far as Russian response is concerned. A few nights later they launched 30-something 'Shaheds' (I forgot the Russian name for that) and a similar number of cruise+ballistic missiles at Kyiv, [according](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-65524104) to Ukraine. But overall these numbers don't seem unusual, e.g. compared [to March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022%E2%80%932023_Russian_strikes_against_Ukrainian_infrastructure#March), when Russia claimed it was responding to a ground incursion by Ukrainians killing civilians in the Bryansk region (one of the areas from where Ukraine [says](https://www.rferl.org/a/ukraine-russia-bakhmut-drones/32391136.html) Shaheds are launched).

As far as Western reponse goes, many expressed [skepticism](https://www.cnbc.com/2023/05/04/did-russia-stage-the-kremlin-drone-attack-it-blamed-on-ukraine-.html) about the Russian claims about the drone attack on the Kremlin, while the other kind of events, like [claims of] ground infiltrations receive little attention in the Western press. (Also, Russia even claimed the Kremlin drone explosions were “dictated” in Washington, a claim strongly [denied](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/may/04/russia-accuses-us-of-being-behind-drone-attack-on-kremlin-putin) by the US.)

Just in general terms, while the White House said (previous source) it "is certainly not encouraging or enabling Ukraine to strike beyond its borders", the UK MoD [said](https://news.yahoo.com/uk-says-backs-ukraines-attack-105112839.html) (last year) that "It is completely legitimate for Ukraine to be targeting in Russia's depth in order to disrupt the logistics, that if they weren't disrupted would directly contribute to death and carnage on Ukrainian soil." So that's the political rather than the legal limit that Ukraine has to deal with.

As far as the [2023] Moscow parade goes, for various reasons, Russia [has](https://www.cnbc.com/2023/05/10/putins-one-tank-military-parade-was-an-embarrassment-for-russia.html) reduced the amount modern weaponry involved to practically nothing this year. Apparently the only tank displayed was a single (WW2 vintage) T-34. (This is in contrast with 2021, for example, [when](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2021/03/11/russia-to-display-advanced-armata-tanks-at-red-square-parade-a73209) dozens of modern tanks were showcased.) The personnel involved in the 2023 parade was also reduced, and "the majority were auxiliary, paramilitary forces, and cadets from military training establishments [... while] the only personnel from deployable formations of regular forces were contingents of Railway Troops and military police.” (according to one Western source). So, legally perhaps still a valid target, but substantially more difficult politically than if e.g. columns of modern tanks were still involved.

Comment: FWTW, in the context of WW2, the British [disrupted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJD38t9noxE) one of Goring's and one of Goebbels's speeches [on the same day--some Nazi anniversary] with Mosquito bombing runs (and AA response) that could be heard over the German radio.