# Do wars on foreign soil often affect military celebrations?

Tags: military, public-opinion, policy, protests

Many countries hold annual military celebrations of various kinds. How have these been affected when they were in another war? On foreign soil of course.

I'm looking for examples of countries canceling specific celebrations, or maybe ramping them up compared to peacetime. Interesting even if it's local events, but perfect if it's possible to infer some statistics.

How large did foreign wars get before stopping parades at home?
Was there a marked difference for unpopular wars such as Vietnam?

Inspired by this question: [Are military units marching in military parades considered military or civilian targets?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72895/are-military-units-marching-in-military-parades-considered-military-or-civilian?noredirect=1#comment301539_72895)

Comment: It's rare for a country to hold military parades or celebrations during wartime. Citizens in wartime are disturbed and frightened, and likely to wonder why these soldiers are prancing around in dress uniforms, not fighting to keep everyone safe. I don't believe even the Nazis did it, and the Nazis *luuuuved* their parades.

Comment: @TedWrigley Good point. I've edited this to focus on wars on foreign soil.

Comment: @TedWrigley: Of course, in the case of the particular parade that I assume inspired this question, both the government and a significant portion of its citizens believe that there is no war to be disturbed by and frightened about.

Comment: The US generally didn't have Soviet- or French-style parades. Although Trump wanted to change that. Also, it would probably help if you narrowed down your Q a bit, e.g. including a country tag. It's a bit broad right now, IMHO.